# No finding tag with XMLStarlet that contains &gt;

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

I'm working with XMLStarlet in a bash script to basically find specific XML nodes based on what has changed on git within that file.
This is working fine until we hit a node that needs to be searched that contains `&gt;` as  part of it's value.
Example of the node that I want to find:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <labels>
        <fullName>Button_Value_Get_Data</fullName>
        <categories>Button Value</categories>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>Value for Button to get Data</shortDescription>
        <value>&gt; GET VEHICLE DATA</value>
    </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

This is the command that I'm running:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" -t -c "//x:labels[x:value/text()=\"&gt; GET VEHICLE DATA\"]/x:fullName" -n myFile.xml
```

This same command works great when the value that needs to be searched doesn't contain `&gt;`.
Is there a way to be able to search this? Or is this an xmlstarlet limitation?
Thank you.

Comment: BTW, it would be helpful to ensure that your example is complete enough to let others test it -- in this case that means including `xmlns` in the XML. If your input document doesn't *have* any `xmlns`, that implies a completely unrelated problem causing the match to fail.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the file is huge and that's why I just put the piece that concerns. But based on your suggestion I included the root nodes and the xlmns piece as well. Take into account that I'm ensuring the xlmns piece is not the issue as I'm stating that the search works for other nodes that do not contain the `&gt;` piece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&gt;` is an encoding of `>`. If you use the literal value in your expression, it matches properly:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" -t -c "//x:labels[x:value/text()=\"> GET VEHICLE DATA\"]/x:fullName" -n test.xml
<fullName xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">Button_Value_Get_Data</fullName>
```

Comment: Ok, weird that I have to convert it back to the literal, do you know why is that?

Comment: @FranciscoRiccomagno: or use: `xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" -t -c "//x:labels[x:value/text()='> GET VEHICLE DATA']/x:fullName" -n test.xml`

Comment: @Cyrus, ...some older versions of XMLStarlet only honored double quotes for strings. If the OP is using a build from the last several years they're fine anyhow, *but*.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you for this hint. This might work with older xmlstarlet, too: `xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" -t -c '//x:labels[x:value/text()="> GET VEHICLE DATA"]/x:fullName' -n test.xml`