# XMLstarlet not finding text with &quot; in it

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

I'm using XMLstarlet through a Bash script to search for changes done in Git and create a new XML file that contains only the changed nodes.
Working as expected, but I do not manage to match a String containing  entity `&quot;`.

The XML looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomLabels xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<labels>
        <fullName>Your_Previously_Selected_Rates_Not_Applicable</fullName>
        <categories>Error</categories>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>Your Previously Selected Rates Not Applicable</shortDescription>
        <value>The rate previously selected isn&apos;t eligible. Please click on &quot;Select&quot; to select a new one.</value>
</labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

Previously we were having issues with `&apos;` but we fixed it by replacing it within the script to use `'` instead. Was trying to do the same with `&quot;` to be replaced with `"` but this is messing up the commands in bash.
The command that we are running is:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" -t -c "//x:labels[x:value/text()=\"The rate previsouly selected isn't eligible. Please click on &quot;Select&quot; to select a new one.\"]/x:fullName" -n CustomLabels.labels
```

Any clue what I might need to do in order to be able to find this text?

Comment: What is the `CustomLabels.labels` at the end supposed to be/do? Strings generally only make sense in XMLStarlet's command-line format when preceded by `-v` or such. Or is that a filename?

Comment: BTW, keep in mind that XMLStarlet creates XSLT templates. You can always tell it to dump the current query to a template and edit/inspect it in that form.

Comment: Can you also paste the error you get?

Comment: I think this is the same as your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170642/no-finding-tag-with-xmlstarlet-that-contains-gt (just a different particular character)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy CustomLabels.labels is the xml file.

Comment: @el-teedee there is no error, it's just not returning any finding

Comment: @npostavs yes, but this has the particularity that the character is the quotation mark encoded.

Answer (score 1):

This is messy.

Essentially you have to take care of two things.

1. Bash quoting
2. XPath does not have a form of escaping quotes.

The trick is to use a *concatination*:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" \
   -t -c "//x:labels[x:value/text()=concat('The rate previously selected isn',\"'\",'t eligible. Please click on \"Select\" to select a new one.')]/x:fullName"
```

The rules are:

1. Use double quotes to define your XPath. This way you can still escape the double quotes and use single quotes for the `concat` function.

   ```
   ... -t -c "//x:lab...x:fullName"
   ```
2. Escape the single quotes you have from your `isn't` by a string entry in your `concat` function which is written with escaped double-quotes.

   ```
   ...ted isn',\"'\",'t elig...
   ```
3. Write all other entries of `concat` in single quotes and bash-escape any double quotes:

   ```
   ...,'t elig... on \"Select\" to ...
   ```

Comment: wow, the problem is that this is an automatic script and the text in values will vary. So I don't know if a `&quot;` will come in the text or not

Comment: @FranciscoRiccomagno as far as I know, xmlstarlet treats `&quote;` and the normal quote as the same. The same accounts for other symbols. That is one of the many reasons why you should never parse XML with regex.

Comment: @FranciscoRiccomagno So in short, this should work on your problem. I did test it and it worked on your example.

Comment: @FranciscoRiccomagno Sorry I might have misunderstood you. If you say you don't know the text in values, how do you know then which label you want to select? I do believe however that this is another question which you should ask. If you like this answer feel free to accept it. If you ask a new question, ill happily help out.